# Few conditions in nginx satisfy

Tags: http, nginx, .htpasswd

I am currently trying to allow the access to a folder in nginx to anyone who meets any of these conditions:

- Access from 10.0.0.0/24 subnet.
- Access from 192.168.1.0/24 subnet and authenticate.

I have the following code for that location:

```
location /private {
        satisfy any;

        allow 10.0.0.0/24;
        deny all;

        auth_basic      "Admin access";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

But that does not work, since I am looking to allow the access for anyone that comes from 10.0.0.0/24 (no authentication) OR for anyone that comes from 192.168.1.0/24 and authenticates.

The above code lets get in the 10.0.0.0/24 people without authentication and everyone who authentifies, so I want to only allow people from 192.168.1.0/24 to authenticate, in any other case, it will deny access.

Answer (score 0):

Once I tried to do the same and can't manage to do it with only `allow`/`deny`/`auth` rules. What you can try to do is

```
map $remote_addr $disallow {
    ~^10\.0\.0\.     "";
    ~^192\.168\.1\.  "";
    default          1;
}
server {
    ...
    location /private {
        if ($disallow) { return 403; }
        satisfy any;

        allow 10.0.0.0/24;
        deny all;

        auth_basic      "Admin access";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   }
   ...
}
```